# Access the property of a property

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I have the following query, that I ran on the [wikidata query service web interface](https://query.wikidata.org/#%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fobject%20%3FobjectLabel%20%3Fmass%20%3FmassUnitLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP397%20wd%3AQ525.%20%20%23%20the%20object%20should%20have%20the%20sun%20as%20parent%20astronomical%20body%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fstatus.%20%20%23%20instance%20of%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP2067%20%3Fmass.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20Here%20are%20the%20accepted%20object%20status%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fstatus%20%7Bwd%3AQ128207%20wd%3AQ121750%20wd%3AQ1319599%7D.%20%20%23%20terrestrial%20planet%2C%20gas%20giant%2C%20ice%20giant%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20automatically%20use%20the%20english%20label%20for%20%3FxLabel%20variables%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?objectLabel ?mass
WHERE {
  ?object wdt:P397 wd:Q525.  # the object should have the sun as parent astronomical body
  ?object wdt:P31 ?status.
  ?object wdt:P2067 ?mass.

  # Here are the accepted object status
  VALUES ?status {wd:Q128207 wd:Q121750 wd:Q1319599}.  # terrestrial planet, gas giant, ice giant

  # automatically use the english label for ?xLabel variables 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

I found that the [mass](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2067) value is given in **a specific [unit](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2237), yottagram in case of the Earth**.
How can I access this information ?

I tried to add something like:

```
?mass   wdt:P2237 ?mass_unit.
```

But, expectedly, this doesn't work because `?mass` is an integer, not an object referencing the Earth mass.
Using the property itself as a subject doesn't work neither:

```
?object wdt:P2067 ?mass.
wd:P2067 wdt:P2237 ?massUnit.
```

This [returns](https://query.wikidata.org/#%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fobject%20%3FobjectLabel%20%3Fmass%20%3FmassUnitLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP397%20wd%3AQ525.%20%20%23%20the%20object%20should%20have%20the%20sun%20as%20parent%20astronomical%20body%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fstatus.%20%20%23%20instance%20of%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP2067%20%3Fmass.%0A%20%20wd%3AP2067%20wdt%3AP2237%20%3FmassUnit.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20Here%20are%20the%20accepted%20object%20status%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fstatus%20%7Bwd%3AQ128207%20wd%3AQ121750%20wd%3AQ1319599%7D.%20%20%23%20terrestrial%20planet%2C%20gas%20giant%2C%20ice%20giant%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20automatically%20use%20the%20english%20label%20for%20%3FxLabel%20variables%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D) all tuples with all available units. (Earth is associated with 5972.37 kilograms, 5972.37 yottagrams, 5972.37 solar mass, etc)

Also, chaining the properties leads to [no results](https://query.wikidata.org/#%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fobject%20%3FobjectLabel%20%3Fmass%20%3FmassUnitLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP397%20wd%3AQ525.%20%20%23%20the%20object%20should%20have%20the%20sun%20as%20parent%20astronomical%20body%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fstatus.%20%20%23%20instance%20of%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP2067%20%3Fmass.%0A%20%20%3Fobject%20wdt%3AP2067%2Fwdt%3AP2237%20%3FmassUnit.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20Here%20are%20the%20accepted%20object%20status%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fstatus%20%7Bwd%3AQ128207%20wd%3AQ121750%20wd%3AQ1319599%7D.%20%20%23%20terrestrial%20planet%2C%20gas%20giant%2C%20ice%20giant%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20automatically%20use%20the%20english%20label%20for%20%3FxLabel%20variables%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D):

```
?object wdt:P2067/wdt:P2237 ?massUnit.
```

I imagine that I need to use, not the property itself, but an instance of it linking specifically the Earth and the integer that describes its mass.

How access the unit information ? (in case of Earth, [Yottagram](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q613726))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How Wikidata is represented in RDF (and thus in SPARQL) is described at MediaWiki.org page [*Wikibase/Indexing/RDF Dump Format*](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format).

The relevant part is that, in your case, `wdt:P2067` directly gives you just the value, but if you instead use `p:P2067`, you get the whole *statement*. From there, you can use `psv:P2067` to get a *value node*. And from there, you can use `wikibase:quantityAmount` to get the mass (just like you could with `wdt:P2067`), but you can also use `wikibase:quantityUnit` to get the entity representing the unit.

So, the whole query could look like this:

```
SELECT ?objectLabel ?mass ?massUnitLabel
WHERE {
  ?object wdt:P397 wd:Q525.  # the object should have the sun as parent astronomical body
  ?object wdt:P31 ?status.

  ?object p:P2067/psv:P2067 ?massValue.
  ?massValue wikibase:quantityAmount ?mass.
  ?massValue wikibase:quantityUnit ?massUnit.

  # Here are the accepted object status
  VALUES ?status {wd:Q128207 wd:Q121750 wd:Q1319599}.  # terrestrial planet, gas giant, ice giant

  # automatically use the english label for ?xLabel variables 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

If you wanted, you could eliminate the `?massValue` variable by using the following code:

```
?object p:P2067/psv:P2067 [
  wikibase:quantityAmount ?mass;
  wikibase:quantityUnit ?massUnit ]
```

Answer (score 0):

RDF literals are typed by XSD datatypes, and SPARQL's `datatype()` can be used to find the type.  So try this in your `SELECT` statement to find the type for `?mass`:

```
SELECT ?objectLabel ?mass (datatype(?mass) AS ?masstype)
....
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question. According to the question, the value is an integer, but OP wants to know what unit is actually used.  So the value might be 42, but OP wants to know "42 of what?"

Comment: 42 of xsd:integer is on possible answer.

Comment: The mass of an object is not 42 integers, it's 42 kg (for example).  Take a look at the wikidata entry for [Earth](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2), for example.  In the entry for mass, it says "5.97±0.01 yottagram".  OP is asking how to retrieve yottagram.  I'd have represented this with RDF by something like `:earth :mass [ :extent 5.97 ; :unit :yottagram ]`.  It's not clear how Wikidata encodes this, but it seems to be present in the data in some format.  Is that available in the RDF view of the data, and if so, how can it be queried using SPARQL?

Comment: `OP is asking how to retrieve yottagram`

Exactly. I've edited the question in order to make it clear.